# Solve the recurrence relation $a_n=a_{n-1}+2n+3a_{n-3}?$

Tags: recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

I am currently solving a recurrence relation but I got stuck since I am not even able to find the basic root of the auxiliary equations.

Comment: Do you mean $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2n + 3a_{n-3}$ or $a_n = a_{n-2} + 2 a_{n-2} + 3 a_{n-3}$ (or something else entirely)?

Comment: First one!!!!!!

Comment: Do you have initial conditions?

Comment: Initial conditions are varying.

Comment: Like in one case a(0)=1,a(1)=2,a(2)=3 so from here a(3) comes 12

Comment: Let $a_n=b_n+p+qn$ to eliminate $n$

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite this as
\begin{align*}
a_{n+3} = a_{n+2} + 2(n+3) + 3a_n
\end{align*}
The generating function for this sequence is
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x) - a_0 - a_1x - a_2x^2}{x^3} = \frac{f(x) - a_0 - a_1x}{x^2} + \frac{2(3 - 2x)}{(1-x)^2} + 3f(x)
\end{align*}
Solving for $f(x)$ gives us
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \color{blue}{\frac{a_0(x-1)}{(3x^3+x-1)}} + \color{red}{\frac{a_1 x(x-1)}{(3x^3+x-1)}} - \color{green}{\frac{a_2x^2}{(3x^3+x-1)}} - \color{orange}{\frac{2(3-2x)x^3}{(x-1)^2(3x^3+x-1)}}
\end{align*}
Let $r_1, r_2, r_3$ be the [roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%203*x%5E3%20%2B%20x%20-%201%20%3D%200) of $3x^3 + x - 1=0$. Then the series expansion of the blue term is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left\{\frac{a_0}{3}\left(\frac{1 - r_1}{r_1^{n+1}(r_1 - r_2)(r_1 - r_3)} + \frac{1 - r_2}{r_2^{n+1}(r_2 - r_1)(r_2 - r_3)} + \frac{1 - r_3}{r_3^{n+1}(r_3 - r_1)(r_3 - r_2)}\right)\right\}}_{p_n}x^n
\end{align*}
Similarly, the red portion is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left\{\frac{a_1}{3}\left(\frac{r_1(1 - r_1)}{r_1^{n+1}(r_1 - r_2)(r_1 - r_3)} + \frac{r_2(1 - r_2)}{r_2^{n+1}(r_2 - r_1)(r_2 - r_3)} + \frac{r_3(1 - r_3)}{r_3^{n+1}(r_3 - r_1)(r_3 - r_2)}\right)\right\}}_{q_n}x^n
\end{align*}
The green portion is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left\{\frac{a_2}{3}\left(\frac{r_1^2}{r_1^{n+1}(r_1 - r_2)(r_1 - r_3)} + \frac{r_2^2}{r_2^{n+1}(r_2 - r_1)(r_2 - r_3)} + \frac{r_3^2}{r_3^{n+1}(r_3 - r_1)(r_3 - r_2)}\right)\right\}}_{r_n}x^n
\end{align*}
**Exercise** Find the series expansion for the orange term, and call the coefficients as $s_n$.

Finally, your sequence can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
a_n = p_n + q_n - r_n - s_n
\end{align*}
There is some heavy simplification you can do. For example, you can express
\begin{align*}
p_n + q_n - r_n=\sum_{t=1}^{3}\frac{1}{r_t^{n+1}}g_t(a_0, a_1, a_2, r_1, r_2, r_3)
\end{align*}
For functions $g_1, g_2, g_3$, which you can pre-compute in a computer implementation.