# Recurrence Relation help me

Tags: recurrence-relations

please, someone, solve this recurrence relation
$$T(n)=T(n-1)+2n+3T(n-3)$$
if $$(T0=1,T1=2,T2=3)$$

Comment: This is the third time that the question is asked today! See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3077188/solve-recurrence-relation-a-n-3-a-n-3-a-n-1-2-n/3077253#3077253

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you’re the one meant to solve it.